# Bootstrap navbar stacks and hides content when resized to mobile size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a standard BS fixed navbar followed by a container-fluid. The navbar has 4 columns, each a different background color.

When I resize the browser window to as small as it will go, the 4 columns stack vertically.

This means that some of the content is hidden beneath the stacked columns.

I'm aware that when using the navbar you should use a padding-top, and that works, but I don't want to have my padding-top set to a large value as it creates a large gap when the page is maximized/not in mobile size.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top custom-header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 first"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 second"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 third"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 fourth"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid body-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h1 class="pull-left">This text is hidden when window resized to small width</h1>
            <h2 class="pull-right">This text is still displayed</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

End goal is to have both the h1 and h2 appear below the stacked navbar.

Comment: When you say hidden you mean that you have to scroll down in order to see the h1 and h2 or that it's completely hidden (behind your navbar)?

Comment: Can you use different values of padding for mobile / tablet / desktop to solve this?

Comment: the h1 is behind my navbar

Comment: @Tibbelit maybe but not sure how to do this, not well-versed in BS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use different padding values for different devices / resolutions (ie mobile/desktop). Look at the documentation here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-media-queries

```css
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

So you can do like this for example

```css
.body-content {
    padding-top: 100px; /* more space under the menu */
}

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
    .body-content {
        padding-top: 50px; /* less space under the menu */
    }
}
```

Comment: should have mentioned I am using BS 3.4, but does this still apply?

Comment: Yes, samt concept applies - I have updated the code to match the documentation for Bootstrap v3.4

Comment: Final questions - are @screen-md-min less variables? Can I use actual values instead? And can I use equations lile > and < ?

Comment: Yes you can use media queries "as usual" as well as Bootstraps own variables, for examples see here (or just google): https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp